# Set the Formula of an Excel Cell in a C# function

Tags: c#, .net, excel, user-defined-functions

I have created an Automation Add-in for Excel,implemented as a C# class library, which contains a UDF wrapper.(I do not use VSTO)

What I would like to do in my UDF, is to:

1>get the cell address where the formula was entered;

2>set the formula of that cell to one of my own;

I have already done point 1> as follows:

```
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range target = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excelApp.get_Caller(System.Type.Missing);

  string cellAddress = target.get_Address(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

  //Perform some operations based on address

  //Assign a formula to my cell (This does not work !)
  target.Formula ="=SUM(2,2)"
```

This should work according to the MSDN documentation from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.formula%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

What am I doing wrong ? Is there any other way I can set the formula of the cell?

Thanks,

Comment: should it be `cellAddress.Formula="=SUM(2,2)"` ?

Comment: nope. "cellAddress" is a string which just stores the cell address for further processing. "target" is the Excel Range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UDF can only return a value to its calling cell - it is not allowed to overwrite its own formula (or alter the contents of any other cell). You would need to create a command to do that.

Comment: hi, can you elaborate a bit more on that ? what do you mean by "command" ?

Comment: "command" is a piece of code launched by a button or event or basically anything other than a formula.

Answer (score 1):

'=SUM(2,2)' is same to '2+2';

if you want add the cells, for example 'A1' and 'A4', you should use this format '=SUM(A1,A4)'

or you want add the cell from 'A1' to 'A4', you shou use '=SUM(A1:A4)'.

or whole column 'B', '=SUM(B:B)'.

Answer (score 0):

try this target .set_Value(RangeValueDataType: Type.Missing, value: "=SUM(2,2)");

Comment: nope, it doesn't work. here's the error message, i cant make any sense of it:
     Encountered an exception:
 Message = Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
 Type = System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
 Stack =    at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.set_Value(Object RangeValueDataType, Object value)

Comment: can you debug and check if you are getting value for target, or it throws exception, also as you are using GetActiveObject run taskmanager and close other instance of excel if there is one

Comment: yes, I am getting a reference to the "target" object, and can access the get_Address method. I can even read the target.formula, as in:

    string f = target.formula;

but cannot set the formula;
and yes i checked, i have only one instance of excel running.